# Why casting is not required in Expression Language in JSP 's?

Tags: jsp, el

So I have this sample class:

```
public class SuperHero implements Serializable{

    private String firstName, lastName;
    private int age;
    // getters, setter etc..
```

Assume I have a superHero attribute in servletContext.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    final SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero("Koray", "Tugay", 31);
    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("superHero", superHero);
}
```

This will work fine in a jsp file:

```
${superHero.firstName}
<br/>
${superHero.lastName}
<br/>
${superHero.age}
```

But in a Servlet I will need to cast it:

```
final SuperHero superHero = (SuperHero) getServletContext().getAttribute("superHero");
```

So who is actually doing the magic, the JSP or the {Expression Language}, and how does it work ?

Comment: The expression language uses [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: The expression language is doing the magic, by being a *dynamically typed* language, while Java is a *statically typed* language. You can google those terms to learn more.